# ZXing 1.6 iPhone Barcodes building error

Tags: iphone, zxing

I have downloaded ZXing 1.6 and am trying to open the project in the folder which names "Barcodes".

After building the project,it show error. How was the problem solved? 
//==========================================================================

> > > **Compile LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp …in/Users/waltinmis/code/ZXing/zxingiphone/iphone/Barcodes/…/…/cpp/core/src/zxing/common**
> > >
> > > CompileC /Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LocalBlockBinarizer.o ../../cpp/core/src/zxing/common/LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp normal armv7 c++ com.apple.compilers.gcc.4_2
> > >           cd /Users/waltonmis/code/ZXing/zxing_iphone/iphone/Barcodes
> > >           setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
> > >           setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
> > >           /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Weffc++ -Woverloaded-virtual -Wmissing-braces -Wswitch -Wunused-variable -Wshadow -Wfour-char-constants -Wnewline-eof -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk -gdwarf-2 -fvisibility=hidden -mno-thumb -miphoneos-version-min=4.0.1 -iquote /Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/zxingcore-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/zxingcore-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/zxingcore-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/zxingcore-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I../../cpp/core/src -I../ZXingWidget/Classes -I/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -c /Users/waltonmis/code/ZXing/zxing_iphone/iphone/Barcodes/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/common/LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp -o /Users/waltonmis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZXing-gdacjujnftryijcugtfwgrnfuooh/Build/Intermediates/ZXing.build/Debug-iphoneos/zxingcore.build/Objects-normal/armv7/LocalBlockBinarizer.o
> > >
> > > arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Users/waltonmis/code/ZXing/zxing_iphone/iphone/Barcodes/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/common/LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp: No such file or directory
> > >       arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: warning: '-x c++' after last input file has no effect
> > >       arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
> > >
> > > **Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1**

//=================================================================================

> > > PS: my device is iPhone OS 4.0.1.
> > >
> > > Develop environment is Mac OS X 10.7.
> > >
> > > iOS SDK 4.2.
> > >
> > > ```
> > > http://www.sendspace.com/file/ludlvq  <- ZXing 1.6
> > > ```

***Any answer is appreciated.***

Comment: Your development enviornment is under NDA, so you should not talk about this here, try in the apple dev forum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that Xcode can't find the file "/Users/waltonmis/code/ZXing/zxing_iphone/iphone/Barcodes/cpp/core/src/zxing/common/LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp". Check to see if it might have been moved or deleted.

PS: "Develop environment is Mac OS X 10.7." You're running Mac OS X Lion?